# Access to getters in actions vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I would like to access the state of my app in actions in Vuex. Here is the state :

```js
const state = () => ({
    profileInfos: {},
    formationData: {},
    exercicesDoneData: [],
    categoriesDone: [],
    listCategories: []
});
```

When I try to access it through an action like this :

```js
getRules({ state }) {
    console.log(state)
}
```

The result is fine in console :
[Result in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFFMM.png)

My issue is that each variable is empty when I console log like this `console.log(state.formationData)`

Do you have any clues where I am wrong ?

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) to show the issue happening.

Comment: Please paste the text content of what you're seeing in the console rather than link a screenshot. That'll make it easier for others to help you diagnose.